# Problema con un código para un BusinessProcess en Jscript

Tags: javascript, codificación, proceso

Holas buenas tardes.
Lo que sucede es que tengo el siguiente código:

```
function Move() {
//debugger;
//Control var (boolean)
var moveToNext = true;

//gets the stageObject
var stageObj = Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveStage();

// Returns a collection of steps in the stage.
var stepsCollection = stageObj.getSteps();

//loop on the stepsColletion
for (var i = 0; i < stepsCollection.getLength(); ++i) {
    // Returns the logical name of the attribute associated to the step.
    var stepAttributeName = stepsCollection.get(i).getAttribute();

    // Retrieves the data value for an attribute.
    var attributeValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(stepAttributeName).getValue();
        }
    //if attribute is null set moveToNext to false
    if ((attributeValue == null)||(attributeValue == false)){
        moveToNext = false;
        }

// If all attributes contain data
if (moveToNext) {
    //Move to the next stage
    Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext();
}
}
```

Y todo funciona perfecto. Sin embargo, cuando voy de `Fase 3` a `Fase 4`, deja de verificar los elementos y sigue de largo (Es decir, que vuelve `moveToNext` a `true` sin importar si hay `null`s o `var = false`). Alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: viendo tu código la causa puede ser que attributeValue en la última iteración del bucle tiene un valor válido, por eso aunque tengas valores  null o false no vas a poner moveToNext a false.

Answer (score 0):

Con esta modificacion moveToNext se irá calculando en cada iteración de bucle y si hay un fallo en algún momento lo marcará con **false**. Si, lo que quieres es dejar de comprobar cuando encuentres un error también puedes hacer un break cuando moveToNext sea **false**.

```
function Move() {
 //debugger;
 //Control var (boolean)
 var moveToNext = true;

 //gets the stageObject
 var stageObj = Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveStage();

 // Returns a collection of steps in the stage.
 var stepsCollection = stageObj.getSteps();

 //loop on the stepsColletion
 for (var i = 0; i < stepsCollection.getLength(); ++i) {
     // Returns the logical name of the attribute associated to the step.
    var stepAttributeName = stepsCollection.get(i).getAttribute();

    // Retrieves the data value for an attribute.
    var attributeValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(stepAttributeName).getValue();

    moveToNext = moveToNext && !(attributeValue == null || attributeValue == false)
 }

 // If all attributes contain data
 if (moveToNext) {
     //Move to the next stage
     Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext();
 }
}
```